# Delete cycles of given length from graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

I have a complete graph and need to delete as few edges as possible from the graph so that no cycles of a given length `k` are contained in the graph.

I was thinking about running DFS and removing edges it didn't use but the problem is all smaller cycles will be deleted as well and I need to remove as few edges as possible.

For example for K<sub>5</sub> and k=3 I can remove 4 edges, for K<sub>4</sub>, k=3 I can remove 2 (shown on picture below).[image]

Comment: Rotate the graph or swap the position of a pair of vertices and the black edges will be in the position of the red edges. There are many, many more cycles of the desired length in the complete graphs that you are not identifying and the set will cover all edges.

Comment: Also, how does deleting the 2 red edges from K_4 leave a cycle of 3 edges?

Comment: For given k (in this case 3) I want to delete all cycles of length of k, so after removing red edges from K_4 there are no cycles of length of 3

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it clear enough, in a complete graph there should be no cycle of length of `k` if I pick any `k`-vertices subgraph